# Change the current language of the quill.js grammar checker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, text-editor, quill, rich-text-editor

I added a grammar checker to my quill. js text editor (beyondgrammar). Everything works fine for correcting and suggesting words, synonyms, etc. On the other hand most of the people who will use the text editor will do it in French, so I want the current language to be localization or I want to force it. (Currently the correction also works with French, but I have to go and select it). I tried with this link:

https://jsfiddle.net/prowriting/L9an64d7/

and replaced the

[{beyondgrammar: ['en-US', 'en-GB', false]}] with [{ beyondgrammar: ['fr-FR', 'fr-CA', false]}]
or this [{beyondgrammar: ['fr-FR', false]}], I have also set true and the language is still English (United States).

Here is my code for my entire quill editor (there is also a word counter):

//Limite de mots pour un texte de présentation

```
var limit = 3700;

Quill.register('modules/counter', Counter);

window.BeyondGrammar.initBeyondGrammar();

var quill1 = new Quill('#editor_etab', {
    theme: 'snow',
    modules: {
        toolbar: {
            container: [
                [{ header: ['1', '2', '3', false] }],
                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link'],
                [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
                ['clean'],
                [{ beyondgrammar: ['fr-FR', 'fr-CA', true] }]
            ],
            handlers: {
                beyondgrammar: window.BeyondGrammar.getToolbarHandler(quill1)
            }
        },
        counter: {
            container: '#counterEtab',
            unit: '@Html.Raw(Resource.Caractere)',
        },
        beyondgrammar: {}
    }
});

//Compteur de mot par section de texte
class Counter {
    constructor(quill, options) {
        this.quill = quill;
        this.options = options;
        this.container = document.querySelector(options.container);
        quill.on('text-change', this.update.bind(this));
        this.update();  // Tenir compte du contenu initial
    }

    calculate() {
        let text = this.quill.getText();
        if (this.options.unit === 'word') {
            text = text.trim();
            // Splitting empty text returns a non-empty array
            return text.length > 0 ? text.split(/\s+/).length : 0;
        } else {
            return text.length;
        }
    }

    update() {
        var length = this.calculate();
        var label = this.options.unit;
        ///À REVOIR
        var caractExced = "(trop élevé)";
        if (length !== 1) {
            label += 's';
        }
        //CHANGER LE NOMBRE
        if (length > limit) {
            this.container.innerText = ' ' + length - 1 + ' / ' + limit + ' ' + label;
            this.container.style.cssText += 'color:red; float:right;padding-right:unset';
            //this.container.style.cssText +=
            'color:white!important;float:right;border:1px solid;border-radius: 5px;background-color: #FF7588;padding-left:5px;padding-right: 5px;';
        }
        else {
            this.container.innerText = ' ' + length + ' / ' + limit + ' ' + label;
            this.container.style.cssText += 'color:#aaa; float:right;padding-right:unset';
            //this.container.style.cssText +=
            'color:white;float:right;border:1px solid;border-radius: 5px;background-color: #16D39A;padding-left:5px;padding-right: 5px;';
        }
    }
}
```

and I also tried this way: but still English which is selected

```
var quill1 = new Quill('#editor_etab', {
    theme: 'snow',
    modules: {
        toolbar: {
            container: [
                [{ header: ['1', '2', '3', false] }],
                ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link'],
                [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
                ['clean'],
                [{ beyondgrammar: ['fr-FR', 'fr-CA', false] }]
            ],
            handlers: {
                beyondgrammar: window.BeyondGrammar.getToolbarHandler(quill1)
            }
        },
        counter: {
            container: '#counterEtab',
            unit: '@Html.Raw(Resource.Caractere)',
        },
        beyondgrammar: {},
      grammar: {
        //[optional] Default language [en-US, en-GB],
        languageIsoCode: "fr-FR",

        //[optional] checking Style. By default is "true"
        checkStyle: true,

        //[optional] checking Spelling. By default is "true"
        checkSpelling: true,

        //[optional] checking Grammar. By default is "true"
        checkGrammar: true,

        //[optional] Show thesaurus information by double click, by default true
        showThesaurusByDoubleClick: true,

        //[optional] Showing context thesaurus, works only if showThesaurusByDoubleClick = true, by default false
        showContextThesaurus: false,
      }

    }
});
```

This is what I want to force:

[image: ScreenS]

and set it to this:

[image]

and if you are able to change the text from "French" to "Français" I am a taker too

Comment: I read the source of the beyond grammar quill plugin, they hardcoded `en-US` during initialisation: https://github.com/prowriting/beyondgrammar-quill/blob/master/src/beyond_grammar_quill.ts#L54  Therefore, there is no way to override it unless 1) you create an issue and ask them to change or 2) you fork the plugin and change it yourself.

Comment: @MicFung Thanks for taking the time to research, I'll try to force it myself otherwise I'll write to them